# Django TextField (CharField) in OuterRef to list with filter _in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried filter queryset in Subquery, but can not use filter _in with OuterRef.

```
UserAccount.objects.filter(groups__name__contains=group).annotate(
        spend=Cast(Subquery(FacebookStatistic.objects.filter(
            ad_account__id_ad__in=[f'act_{el.strip()}' for el in 
                                    str(OuterRef('facebook_ad_accounts')).split(',')],           
            ).annotate(spd=Coalesce(Func('spend', function='Sum'), 0, output_field=FloatField())
                               ).values('spd')
                ), output_field=FloatField()),

            )
```

This filter don't work. Text Field not converting to string

```
str(OuterRef('facebook_ad_accounts'))
```

Plese tell me, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

When using `OuterRef` and `Subquery`, instead of trying to convert OuterRef to a string, create an `OuterRef` for the related field and use it directly in the subquery. Then, obtain the related values and use them in a `__in` lookup. This approach allows you to filter based on a list of strings from `facebook_ad_accounts`:

```
facebook_ad_account_outer_ref = OuterRef('facebook_ad_accounts')

spend_subquery = FacebookStatistic.objects.filter(
    ad_account__id_ad=facebook_ad_account_outer_ref
).annotate(
    spd=Coalesce(Func('spend', function='Sum'), 0, output_field=FloatField())
).values('spd')

facebook_ad_account_ids = UserAccount.objects.filter(
    groups__name__contains=group
).values_list('facebook_ad_accounts', flat=True)

user_accounts = UserAccount.objects.filter(
    groups__name__contains=group
).annotate(
    spend=Cast(Subquery(spend_subquery), output_field=FloatField())
)
```

This approach correctly filters and handles related data in a concise manner.